# I use margin for text to go a little bit up but container its taking a lot of space on screen,why is container taking a lot of spaces on screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I use margin for text to go a little bit up but container is taking a lot of space on screen,why is container taking a lot of spaces on screen?
Code goes here!

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 200.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
              child: Text(
                _text,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

reduce `margin`, margin takes much of space

```
    Column( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
    children: [ Container( margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0), 
child: Center( 
child: Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0), 
child: Text( _text, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), ), ), ), ),
```

Comment: no,the problem remains same,the container is taking the blank spaces,why?

Comment: ya but i want to move my text  a little bit up that why i am giving the value of margin to 300.0
giving 15.0 not taking text to up

Comment: but your question is why container is taking lots of space? , so answer is margin to much giving

Comment: ok,but what is the solution to this?
i want my text up and dont want my container to take such extra space

Comment: try to change mainAxisAlignment to Start or others and test it